# TypeScript - Distributive conditional types

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, frontend, typescript-typings

Talk is cheap,show the code!
By the way, the version of ts I am testing is 4.6.4

```
type ITypeA = ((args: { A: any }) => any) | ((args: { B: any }) => any);

type Test<T> = T extends (args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

// type Result1 = {
//     A: any;
// } | {
//     B: any;
// }
type Result1 = Test<ITypeA>;

// type Result2 = {
//     A: any;
// } & {
//     B: any;
// }
type Result2 = ITypeA extends (args: infer A) => any ? A : never;
```

`Result1` may use 'distributive conditional types' rule in ts, so `type Result1 = { A: any;} | { B: any;}`.

My question is why does `Result2` not apply this rule? Is there any difference between them?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgKuCBBKBeKAKDBDATgcwGcAuKAbyiVOwDsQoBfASjQD4paQWAfTHAkuSgAhanUYtU7TkwDcAKHmhIUOBELAAPHHbo4UCAA9gEGgBNCmPEVIBLGgDMIuSpOniA-JSikaEAG7OCkqIUABK6gCuADbAAIxoqupa8IhIrAoA9JlQuQB6HorK0BGEMcAATImpkChGJuaW-DZQ9k4uSG4cnt6+AUHy2blQBUA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type. For example, take the following:

There is a requirement, you need act on `generic`.

`Result2` acts on known types, there is no generic, whereas `Result1` uses `Test` which in turn uses `generic T`

Comment: Thank you!! I understand! It must act on generic!