# Inlining Typescript generic gives different behavior

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm pretty new to Typescript but I found some very surprising behavior with generics that I cannot find a reasonable explanation to.
Basically, I have a object of the form

```js
const data = {
    "a": {
        include: true,
    },
    "b": {
        include: false,
    },
};
```

and I'm trying to programmatically get a type consisting of all keys with `include == true`, (so the type `"a"` in this case). You can see my code below, with three attempts, one that works and two that fail (they give `never` instead).

Why does inlining the definition of `IncludedKey2` in `Attempt1` change the result (see `Attempt2`).
I think I understand why `Attempt2` and `Attempt3` fail (`(typeof data)[Keys]["include"]` is `boolean` which does not extend `true`), but then I don’t understand why `Attempt1` works.

```js
const data = {
    "a": {
        include: true,
    },
    "b": {
        include: false,
    },
} as const;

type Keys = keyof (typeof data) // Keys = "a" | "b"
type IncludedKey<Id extends Keys> =
    (typeof data)[Id]["include"] extends true
        ? Id : never

// Different version of IncludedKey that uses a conditional type instead of a constrained type parameter
type IncludedKey2<Id> = Id extends Keys ? IncludedKey<Id> : never

// Works
type Attempt1 = IncludedKey2<Keys>; // Attempt1 = "a"

// Fails
// Simple inlining of IncludedKey2
type Attempt2 = Keys extends Keys ? IncludedKey<Keys> : never // Attempt2 = never
type Attempt3 = IncludedKey<Keys> // Attempt3 = never
```

([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAsAKAJABECBAXJrnngJZjAA2ArnAKZlQBODzANBQL698BAEaly+arUYsyAMwR0IPfoL4wEEGKEhQA3LlxQAngAdmMANLMjm9AGtrIWTAAUxs0-hIEAShgB6f0trWxgiAhgAHzDRQ1NzAEkpJmY4KyMAHgS4GGYADyhmMDhNdIgAPjQKN3jPRGQfAG1sgF1Gghp6FIIW3IKikpgOLgo8AH4YbJgyMGYAN2Z2AxxAmAARKllZRaLYBfYIKnAYTySuljTrIYALJBgGJU0UbTgqKCOwBSH4mBpoZgQOU8z3A0HYCBoqW+ZhgJgQ4IAtsxCkscO5EskLukAExZOCVdBTfKFYqlEIwCZnaSpdJ4yozeaLZarADqIHYdggcRhAEEoIUESYoABGNCTTE06y4srlXQBIJ8gVC0XocLMoIAMQhilwqwAylRBXRzDQ6DQaABzE7OKkpS5GbHc8yK5iCqDYsVlPokwZeykS+0ZGXTGCzfbymAut0e9Bhplon5RoUAZjFtqx1iDIUqqyTUFTscZ7CAA))

Comment: I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72387901/typescript-distributive-conditional-types/72390369#72390369) question/answer is almost a duplicate. However, inlined version of `Attempt1` works because `Id` generic argument is distributet.  It means that `IncludedKey<Id>` is applied to each element in the union, in other words to `a` and `b`. In fact, `Attempt1` is a union of `a` and `never`. Because `never` is a union is clashed - you got an `a`. Try to wrap `never` into string and you will get `a | never`. Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/con

Comment: Correct link to [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)